# Update more than one table at the same time in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have table query like

```
UPDATE D 
SET D.VALUE = B.VALUE
FROM 
    DOM D 
INNER JOIN 
    COM C ON C.ID = D.ID
INNER JOIN 
    TOM T ON T.ID = D. ID
WHERE
    D.VALUE <> B.VALUE

UPDATE D 
SET C.VALUE = B.VALUE
FROM 
    DOM D 
INNER JOIN 
    COM C ON C.ID = D.ID
INNER JOIN 
    TOM T ON T.ID = D. ID
WHERE
    D.VALUE <> B.VALUE
```

Here the `where` condition is the same for both queries and also the joins are the same. So can I update the two tables with one `update` statement?

Comment: you can't update more than one table with a single `update` statement.

Comment: you can't update more than one table with a single update statement but you can place all updates in a single transaction so all updates will be commited or rolled back.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot update TWO tables with one Update statement. but you can Update two tables in one transaction by wrapping the two separate updates into one transaction. It achieves the same thing but with a slightly different way.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION 

    UPDATE D 
     SET D.VALUE = B.VALUE
    FROM 
    DOM D 
    INNER JOIN COM C ON C.ID = D.ID
    INNER JOIN TOM T ON T.ID = D. ID
    WHERE D.VALUE <> B.VALUE

    UPDATE D 
       SET C.VALUE = B.VALUE
    FROM 
    DOM D 
    INNER JOIN COM C ON C.ID = D.ID
    INNER JOIN TOM T ON T.ID = D. ID
    WHERE D.VALUE <> B.VALUE

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Comment: I would add `begin try...end try begin catch... end catch`

Comment: @AlexKudryashev Yes if the question was bout error handling I would have suggested that but the question is about Update :)

Comment: "It achieves the same thing" - almost. Constraints are checked at the end of each statement. So if you have a pair of updates where either one, by itself, causes a constraint to be violated, but when considering the pair together the constraints are maintained, then performing two separate updates is not "the same thing" as the hypothetical "update multiple tables simultaneously" statement. Of course, if we had deferrable constraints in SQL Server, we'd be closer to being able to say that multiple updates within a transaction are the same as a single update.

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious solution for this is to write an Update trigger on DOM table. This trigger will take care of TOM and COM tables.

```
Select 1 ID, 10 Value
into DOM
union all
Select 2, 20
union all
Select 3, 30


Select 1 ID, 10 Value
into TOM
union all
Select 2, 20
union all
Select 3, 30


Select 1 ID, 10 Value
into COM
union all
Select 2, 20
union all
Select 3, 30


drop trigger DomUpdate 
create trigger DomUpdate on DOM 
after Update
as 
begin
Update TOM 
set value = i.value 
from TOM t
INNER JOIN 
    inserted I ON I.ID = T. ID

Update COM 
set value = i.value 
from TOM t
INNER JOIN 
    inserted I ON I.ID = T. ID
end
GO

Select D.value 
FROM 
    DOM D 
INNER JOIN 
    COM C ON C.ID = D.ID
INNER JOIN 
    TOM T ON T.ID = D. ID
WHERE
    D.VALUE <> 50

begin tran t1
Update D
set D.value = 50
FROM 
    DOM D 
INNER JOIN 
    COM C ON C.ID = D.ID
INNER JOIN 
    TOM T ON T.ID = D. ID
WHERE
    D.VALUE <> 50
--rollback tran t1
commit tran t1

Select * from DOM
Select * from COM
Select * from TOM
```